# Can not find module in module file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-routing, ionic4

I am getting the following error when calling my module:

Error: Cannot find 'CreateItemPageModule' in '../create-item/create-item.module'

I have checked all the links and names etc. I have deleted the whole file and recreated it, commented out all my imports etc.

My other tabs/routes work fine, its just this one. Deleting and recreating it didn't help and recreating it with just the base skeleton also doesn't work.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Crop } from '@ionic-native/crop/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx'
import { InputListComponentModule } from '../../components/input-list/input-list.module'
import { InputItemComponentModule } from '../../components/input-item/input-item.module'

import { CreateItemProvider } from '../../services/create-item/create-item'
import { CreateItemPage } from './create-item.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CreateItemPage
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        InputListComponentModule,
        InputItemComponentModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        CreateItemPage
    ],
    exports: [
        CreateItemPage
    ],
    providers: [
        CreateItemProvider,
        Crop,
        File
    ]
})
export class CreateItemPageModule { }
```

And:

```
  {
    path: 'pages',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'feed', loadChildren: '../feed/feed.module#FeedPageModule' },
      { path: 'create-item', loadChildren: '../create-item/create-item.module#CreateItemPageModule' },
      { path: 'message', loadChildren: '../message/message.module#MessagePageModule' },
    ]
  },
```

There's no other errors and the rest of the app runs. I have tried removing everything from the ts file it imports too to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a git repo or anything that would help to reproduce the error and be able to debug/check the project structure?

Comment: I'm not allowed to share all the code unfortunately. Though if you have suggestions i can share other bits.

Comment: that create stackblitz example with our project settings and share it here

Comment: This is almost certainly either a spelling error or a missing export clause. The error indicates that the module is being resolved but doesn't export the member. Look at the file `../create-item/create-item.module`

Comment: Please check the file name is all lower case.